# No se cierra UpdateProgress ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo una página en la cual tengo un ImageButton que me genera un excel con un reporte.
El problema es que al darle click al botón se ejecuta el UpdateProgres pero nunca termina de ejecutarse, si bien se genera el excel y lo puedo descargar sin ningun problema, si luego quiero seguir interactuando con la página no puedo hacerlo hasta que refresque la página.
Dejo una vista del problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código .Aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updClientes" runat="server" DisplayAfter="0">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="blur" class="ProgressIndicatorFondoModal">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="ProgressIndicator">
            Procesando <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="16px" ImageUrl="~/Imagenes/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updClientes" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <br />
        <asp:Accordion ID="accFiltros" runat="server" FadeTransitions="True" FramesPerSecond="40" Width="100%"
                    TransitionDuration="200" RequireOpenedPane="false" SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"
                     ContentCssClass="accordionContent" HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeader_selected">
            <Panes>
                <asp:AccordionPane ID="accPaneFiltros" runat="server">
                    <Header>
                        <div class="accordionTitulo">
                            <span class="TituloFiltros" id="TituloFiltros">
                                <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:GD, TituloFiltrosClientes%>"></asp:Literal></span> - Filtros de Búsqueda 
                        </div>
                    </Header>
                    <Content>
                        //Código del panel para filtrar datos
                    </Content>
                </asp:AccordionPane>
            </Panes>
        </asp:Accordion>
        <div style="position: relative; float: left; padding: 5px; border: 1px;">
            <asp:Button ID="btnLimpiar" Text="<%$ Resources:GD, btnLimpiar %>" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:GD, btnLimpiarToolTip %>" runat="server" Width="100px" CssClass="boton" OnClick="btnLimpiar_Click" />
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; float: right; padding: 5px; border: 1px;">
            <asp:Button ID="btnNuevoCliente" runat="server" CssClass="boton" Text="<%$ Resources:GD, btnNuevoCliente %>" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:GD, btnNuevoClienteToolTip %>" OnClick="btnNuevoCliente_Click" />
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; float: left; padding: 5px; border: 1px; margin-top: 35px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMensaje" runat="server" CssClass="MensajeError"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div id="divGrilla1" runat="server" style="overflow: auto; margin-top: 45px">
            <div id="div1" runat="server" style="position: relative; float: left; margin-top: 20px">
                <asp:Label ID="lblCantResultados" runat="server" CssClass="label" Style="font-weight: bold"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMenResultados" runat="server" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div style="position:relative; float: right;"> 
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updBtnExcel">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnExcelClientesListar" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:GD, btnExcelToolTip %>" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Imagenes/botExcel.jpg" 
                                         OnClick="btnExcelClientesListar_Click" Visible="False"/>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Intenté poner el ImageButton dentro de otro UpdatePanel pero no está funcionando, igualmente se ejecuta el UpdateProgress

Código Aspx.cs  del evento Click

```
protected void btnExcelClientesListar_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Session["DatosGvClientes"] != null)
            {
                Armar_Reporte_Excel();   
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("GirosListar.aspx:btnExcelClientesListar_Click", ex);
            this.lblMensaje.Text = Resources.GD.msgErrorGenerico;
        }
    }
```

Dato: Tengo otra página con el mismo código en la cual no tengo este problema.

Comment: ¿Qué lógica tiene el `UpdateProgress`?, `El problema es que al darle click al botón` = ¿cuál botón es el que realiza la acción?. Cuando ha pruebas, mire la consola del navegador, tal vez allí se muestren los errores "mas específicos" que pueda tener con este código.

Comment: El UpdateProgress se ejecuta cada vez que se cargan datos en unos combobox que tiene la página o cuando trae los datos que el usuario solicita. `¿cuál botón es el que realiza la acción?`el ImageButton al cual hice referencia al principio de la pregunta

Comment: Pablo, ¿intentó usar `AsyncPostBackTrigger` para enlazar el ImageButton con el updatepanel? - yo creo que por ahí puede estar el problema. [fuente](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers)

Comment: Con AsyncPostbackTrigger tampoco funciona. En la consola javascript me marca este error: `Error de análisis XML: no se encontraron elementos`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la solución usando `PostBackTrigger`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updBtnExcel">
      <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:ImageButton ID="btnExcelClientesListar" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:GD, btnExcelToolTip %>" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Imagenes/botExcel.jpg" 
                            OnClick="btnExcelClientesListar_Click" Visible="False"/>
      </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
             <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExcelClientesListar"/>
      </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Con esto se termina de ejecutar el UpdateProgress y se puede seguir navegando la página.

Comment: No se le olvide [aceptar su propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Comment: Si, el sitio me permite hacerlo a partir de mañana